# Nested Navigation with drawer and stack navigator in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two navigators one is stack navigator and another one is drawer navigator. What i need is, the app starts with login page ( no splash screen direct login page ) and once singin button clicked it needs to go to dashboard ( which is a stack screen ). And from this dashboard screen Drawer navigator should be available to use. And this drawer navigator has multiple stack navigator screens.

So my structure is like as follows :

```
--AppStackNavigator
  --screen1
  --screen2
  --screen3
--DrawerNavigator
  --screen1(From above and linked above stack navigator here)
  --screen2(From above)
  --screen3(From above)
--AuthStackNavigator
  --screen1
  --screen2(Linking Drawer here)
```

The problem is it couldnt navigate from screen2 to screen1 from drawernavigator and i couldnt bring header name for any of the drawe navigations. Please guide me through, using React Navigation V3.

Here is my code:

```
 const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
   screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
     header: null
  }
 },
  RouteCalendar: {
    screen: RouteCalendar,
    navigationOptions: {
     header: null
   }
 },
 StoreList: {
   screen: StoreList,
   navigationOptions: {
    title: 'Store List'
  }
 },
Training:{
screen: Training,
navigationOptions: {
  header: null
}
 },
});

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
   InitialScreen: {
   screen: AppStackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: "Home",
    }
  },
  Training: {
    screen: Training,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: "Training"
    }
  },
  RoutePlan: {
    screen: RouteCalendar,
    navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: "Route Plan"
    }
   },
{
 contentOptions: {
  activeTintColor: '#127CC1',
},
navigationOptions : ({navigation}) => {
  return {
      headerLeft: (
        <Icon name="md-menu" style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} 
        onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
        />
      )
    }
  }
}
);

const AuthStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{

  LoginScreen: {
   screen: Login,
   navigationOptions: {
    headerTransparent: true
   }
 },
 Dashboard: DrawerNavigator,
});
```

From the above i can navigate to Training , route plan from drawer but from training page i couldnt navigate back to Dashboard Screen. And how to add header for drawer screens. And between , is above structure correct ?

Answer (score 0):

**One way of doing it.**

Drawer Navigator doesn't render it's own header. You have to render header inside its Stack Navigator which has four screens. Try removing

```
navigationOptions: { header: null }
```

from the AppStackNavigator and add the same to `Dashboard: DrawerNavigator` so that it doesn't render it's own Stack Navigator. 
Finally move the navigationOptions from createDrawerNavigator inside the Stack Navigator.

After moving the navigationOptions inside the Stack Navigator you will be able to navigate from screen1 to screen2 using "md-menu" icon.

[Check their docs for further information](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#nesting-drawer-navigators-inside-others)